Social Login with Django Rest Framework and Dj-rest-auth
I have configured social login with Google with dj-rest-auth and Django rest framework. When I sign-up using normal the normal register view from dj-rest-auth, I can't login using the Gmail of same account.
E.g I sign-up up normally using register with email: ifeanyinneji777@gmail.com. and then I tried logging in with Google with the same email.
It says that a user with this email address already exists.
Expecting to be logged in properly using Google.

Assuming you are using ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email", make sure those two settings are set, if you want to allow social accounts to merge with local-onces.
# Authenticate if local account with this email address already exists
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION = True
# Connect local account and social account if local account with that email address already exists
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION_AUTO_CONNECT = True

Docs:
https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/socialaccount/configuration.html
I've created a simple tutorial on how to set up social authentication in Django REST framework
